# JSTL xml parsing

Tags: java, xml, jsp, jstl

I have a small question on the JSTL tab lib.

How can we select all the content of an xml tag.

Let me show you:

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<menu>
<portlet id="publier">
    <titre>Publier</titre>
    <contenu><a target="blank"
            href="#">
            <img src="Logo_32x32_Facebook.png"
                alt="Publier cette info sur Facebook" />
        </a>
    <contenu>
</portlet>
 ...
</menu>
```

JSP file that user JSL:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"  prefix="x" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:import url="./vue/Theme/default/menu.xml" var="menuXML" />
<x:parse xml="${menuXML}" varDom="menuXML" />

<div class="column" id="col1">

<x:forEach select="$menuXML/menu/portlet" var="currentPortlet">
    <div class="portlet" id="<x:out select="@id"/>">
        <div class="portlet-header"><x:out select="$currentPortlet//titre" /></div>
        <div class="portlet-content">
            <x:if select="$currentPortlet//contenu">
                <x:out select="$currentPortlet//contenu"/>
            </x:if>             
            <x:if select="$currentPortlet//lien" >
                <ul>
                    <x:forEach var="lien" select="$currentPortlet//lien" >
                        <li><a href="<x:out select="@url"/>"><x:out select="$lien" /></a></li>
                    </x:forEach>
                </ul>
            </x:if>             
        </div>
    </div>
</x:forEach>
</div>
```

The problem is that think:

```
<x:if select="$currentPortlet//contenu">
    <x:out select="$currentPortlet//contenu"/>
</x:if>
```

When the content contains HTML tags, they are not displayed

How to get all the contents of the "contenu" tag, and not ignore html tags?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

You should try wrapping your html code into a **CDATA** so it is not parsed as XML code.

Like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
...
<contenu>
   <![CDATA[
      <a target="blank"
        href="#">
        <img src="Logo_32x32_Facebook.png"
            alt="Publier cette info sur Facebook" />
      </a> 
   ]]>
<contenu>
...
```

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: XML is supposed to contain only raw data and the formating (HTML tags) is for the JSP part. For instance, instead of putting an A tag and IMG tag, just put the link of you A tag and the image url of your img tag.   <contenu><link>http://stckoverflow.com</link><image><link>Logi_FB.png</link><alt>...</alt>...</image>...</contenu>

Comment: Many thanks to us, i finaly use xsl formatting <xsl:value-of select="contenu" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

And then in the jsp file:

    <c:import url="./vue/Theme/default/menu.xml"
              var="inputDoc" />
    <c:import url="./vue/Theme/default/menu.xsl"
              var="stylesheet" />
    <x:transform xml  = "${inputDoc}"
                 xslt = "${stylesheet}">
    </x:transform>